# Golang atomic.StorePointer(...) behaves weird

Tags: go, atomic

Tried to play with atomic package and got quite a strange behavior, probably didn't understand specification...

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/oPeqwETBpuZ

Code:

```
func main() {
    x := 1
    y := 2
    xp := &x
    yp := &y
    fmt.Println("xp before: ", xp)
    fmt.Println("yp before: ", yp)
    xpu := (unsafe.Pointer)(xp)
    ypu := (unsafe.Pointer)(yp)
    atomic.StorePointer(&xpu, ypu)
    fmt.Println("xp  after: ", xp)
    fmt.Println("yp  after: ", yp)
}
```

Output:

```
xp before:  0xc000100010
yp before:  0xc000100018
xp  after:  0xc000100010
yp  after:  0xc000100018
```

Expected:

```
xp before:  0xc000100010
yp before:  0xc000100018
xp  after:  0xc000100018
yp  after:  0xc000100018
```

**What did I do wrong?**

Comment: `&xpu` is a pointer to `xpu`, so result will be in `xpu` variable

Answer (score 1):

Right way: https://play.golang.org/p/__P_5E4di79

In fact, function needed **int casted to *unsafe.Pointer